# Show menubar in fullscreen

Tags: mac, macos, menu-bar, fullscreen

Yes this is different than other "show menubar in fullscreen"

I have a program where i make my own tests for people in class
and when opening it i have to close all my programs that's ok for me
but when in the program i can't swipe to left or right and can't see the menubar. so my question is is there anything possible with the info.plist to change it to let me show the menubar? (i have a MacBook Air 11inch early 2015 with Mac osx Sierra)

Answer (score 1):

In SystemPreferences->General check "automatically hide and show the menubar".
Then it works like this: you do the app full screen with the green button, the menubar is hidden, move the mouse pointer to the top of the screen and the menubar becomes visible above everything.
added: It works also even when you do not check "automatically hide and show the menubar", a tid bit slower perhaps.
added; you can also set a key combination if you want.

Comment: the app is automatically  on fullscreen and i can't make my window smaller, so thats the problem